# Extract key value in Ansible stdout and use as variable

Tags: ansible

I wanted to get a value of a key from the stdout and use it as a variable. Here's my playbook:

```
---
- name: Get bastion host info
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    rgname: 'newrg'
    bastionname: 'bhname'
  tasks:
  - name: Get bastion host info
    shell: >
      az network bastion show --name "{{ bastionname }}" --resource-group "{{ rgname }}"
    register: bastionhost
  - set_fact:
      bh: "{{ bastionhost.stdout | regex_search ('dnsName(.+)', '\\1') | first }}"

  - name: Add bastion dnsName to group_vars file
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      path: /home/user/group_vars/pprod.yml
      line: 'ansible_ssh_common_args: ''-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@"{{ bh }}""'''
      create: yes
```

When I run the playbook, here's the stdout:

```
"stdout": "{\n  \"dnsName\": \"bst-38b12345-fb01-60c0-ba73-dfb8f18a5f09.bastion.azure.com\",\n  \"etag\": \"W/\\\"402a91d0-74c2-41de-8d45-91eadab53d4a\\\"\",\n  \"id\": \"/subscriptions/1234578-1234-1234-5678-65e084b98765/resourceGroups/newrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bhname\",\n  \"ipConfigurations\": [\n    {\n      \"etag\": \"W/\\\"402a91d0-74c2-41de-8d45-91eadab53d4a\\\"\",\n      \"id\": \"/subscriptions/1234578-1234-1234-5678-65e084b98765/resourceGroups/newrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bhname/bastionHostIpConfigurations/bastion_ip_config\",\n      \"name\": \"bastion_ip_config\",\n      \"privateIpAllocationMethod\": \"Dynamic\",\n      \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",\n      \"publicIpAddress\": {\n        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/1234578-1234-1234-5678-65e084b98765/resourceGroups/newrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/pip\",\n        \"resourceGroup\": \"newrg\"\n      },\n      \"resourceGroup\": \"newrg\",\n      \"subnet\": {\n        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/1234578-1234-1234-5678-65e084b98765/resourceGroups/newrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet/subnets/AzureBastionSubnet\",\n     \"resourceGroup\": \"newrg\"\n      },\n      \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastionHostIpConfigurations\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"location\": \"southeastasia\",\n  \"name\": \"bhname\",\n  \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",\n  \"resourceGroup\": \"newrg\",\n  \"tags\": null,\n  \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts\"\n}",
```

The invocation line from the play:

```
"line": "ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -W %h:%p -q user@\"\": \"bst-38b12345-fb01-60c0-ba73-dfb8f18a5f09.bastion.azure.com\",\"\"'",
```

Result in the file:

```
user@Azure:~$ cat group_vars/pprod.yml
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@"": "bst-38b12345-fb01-60c0-ba73-dfb8f18a5f09.bastion.azure.com",""'
user@Azure:~$
```

Looking at how to extract only the dnsName value (without the quotes and comma) so the pprod.yml will have:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@bst-38b12345-fb01-60c0-ba73-dfb8f18a5f09.bastion.azure.com"'
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you

Edit: To share the debug output. I captured the json in a file for easier referencing (sensitive data masked out):

```
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# cat bastion.json
{
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "az network bastion show --name \"bastion-name\" --resource-group \"rg-name\"\n",
    "delta": "0:00:01.032269",
    "end": "2021-03-05 21:34:10.861829",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "az network bastion show --name \"bastion-name\" --resource-group \"rg-name\"\n",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2021-03-05 21:34:09.829560",
    "stderr": "WARNING: Command group 'network bastion' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "WARNING: Command group 'network bastion' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus"
    ],
    "stdout": "{\n  \"dnsName\": \"bst-38b12345-fb01-60c0-ba73-dfb8f18a5f09.bastion.azure.com\",\n  \"etag\": \"W/\\\"123a10d0-66c2-55de-8d12-65aeiou45d8b\\\"\",\n  \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastion-name\",\n  \"ipConfigurations\": [\n    {\n      \"etag\": \"W/\\\"123a10d0-66c2-55de-8d12-65aeiou45d8b\\\"\",\n      \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastion-name/bastionHostIpConfigurations/bastion_ip_config\",\n      \"name\": \"bastion_ip_config\",\n      \"privateIpAllocationMethod\": \"Dynamic\",\n      \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",\n      \"publicIpAddress\": {\n        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/bastion-publicip\",\n        \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\"\n      },\n      \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\",\n      \"subnet\": {\n        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/subnets/AzureBastionSubnet\",\n     \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\"\n      },\n      \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastionHostIpConfigurations\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"location\": \"southeastasia\",\n  \"name\": \"bastion-name\",\n  \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",\n  \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\",\n  \"tags\": null,\n  \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts\"\n}",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "{",
        "  \"dnsName\": \"bst-38b12345-fb01-60c0-ba73-dfb8f18a5f09.bastion.azure.com\",",
        "  \"etag\": \"W/\\\"123a10d0-66c2-55de-8d12-65aeiou45d8b\\\"\",",
        "  \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastion-name\",",
        "  \"ipConfigurations\": [",
        "    {",
        "      \"etag\": \"W/\\\"123a10d0-66c2-55de-8d12-65aeiou45d8b\\\"\",",
        "      \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastion-name/bastionHostIpConfigurations/bastion_ip_config\",",
        "      \"name\": \"bastion_ip_config\",",
        "      \"privateIpAllocationMethod\": \"Dynamic\",",
        "      \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",",
        "      \"publicIpAddress\": {",
        "        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/bastion-publicip\",",
        "        \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\"",
        "      },",
        "      \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\",",
        "      \"subnet\": {",
        "        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/subnets/AzureBastionSubnet\",",
        "        \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\"",
        "      },",
        "      \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastionHostIpConfigurations\"",
        "    }",
        "  ],",
        "  \"location\": \"southeastasia\",",
        "  \"name\": \"bastion-name\",",
        "  \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",",
        "  \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\",",
        "  \"tags\": null,",
        "  \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts\"",
        "}"
    ]
}[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# vi getjsonvalue.yml
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# cat getjsonvalue.yml
---
- name: Get json data and write to file
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Get bastion host info
    shell: cat bastion.json
    register: bastionhost
  - debug: msg={{ bastionhost.stdout | from_json }}
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# ansible-playbook getjsonvalue.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Get json data and write to file] *********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get bastion host info] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "az network bastion show --name \"bastion-name\" --resource-group \"rg-name\"\n",
        "delta": "0:00:01.032269",
        "end": "2021-03-05 21:34:10.861829",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "az network bastion show --name \"bastion-name\" --resource-group \"rg-name\"\n",
                "_uses_shell": true,
                "argv": null,
                "chdir": null,
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "removes": null,
                "stdin": null,
                "stdin_add_newline": true,
                "strip_empty_ends": true,
                "warn": true
            }
        },
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-03-05 21:34:09.829560",
        "stderr": "WARNING: Command group 'network bastion' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "WARNING: Command group 'network bastion' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus"
        ],
        "stdout": "{\n  \"dnsName\": \"bst-38b12345-fb01-60c0-ba73-dfb8f18a5f09.bastion.azure.com\",\n  \"etag\": \"W/\\\"123a10d0-66c2-55de-8d12-65aeiou45d8b\\\"\",\n  \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastion-name\",\n  \"ipConfigurations\": [\n    {\n      \"etag\": \"W/\\\"123a10d0-66c2-55de-8d12-65aeiou45d8b\\\"\",\n      \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastion-name/bastionHostIpConfigurations/bastion_ip_config\",\n      \"name\": \"bastion_ip_config\",\n      \"privateIpAllocationMethod\": \"Dynamic\",\n      \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",\n      \"publicIpAddress\": {\n        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/bastion-publicip\",\n        \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\"\n      },\n      \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\",\n      \"subnet\": {\n        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/subnets/AzureBastionSubnet\",\n     \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\"\n      },\n      \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastionHostIpConfigurations\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"location\": \"southeastasia\",\n  \"name\": \"bastion-name\",\n  \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",\n  \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\",\n  \"tags\": null,\n  \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts\"\n}",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "{",
            "  \"dnsName\": \"bst-38b12345-fb01-60c0-ba73-dfb8f18a5f09.bastion.azure.com\",",
            "  \"etag\": \"W/\\\"123a10d0-66c2-55de-8d12-65aeiou45d8b\\\"\",",
            "  \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastion-name\",",
            "  \"ipConfigurations\": [",
            "    {",
            "      \"etag\": \"W/\\\"123a10d0-66c2-55de-8d12-65aeiou45d8b\\\"\",",
            "      \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastion-name/bastionHostIpConfigurations/bastion_ip_config\",",
            "      \"name\": \"bastion_ip_config\",",
            "      \"privateIpAllocationMethod\": \"Dynamic\",",
            "      \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",",
            "      \"publicIpAddress\": {",
            "        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/bastion-publicip\",",
            "        \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\"",
            "      },",
            "      \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\",",
            "      \"subnet\": {",
            "        \"id\": \"/subscriptions/70b030a1-10f6-9876-9ea8-11e084b12345/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/subnets/AzureBastionSubnet\",",
            "        \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\"",
            "      },",
            "      \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/bastionHostIpConfigurations\"",
            "    }",
            "  ],",
            "  \"location\": \"southeastasia\",",
            "  \"name\": \"bastion-name\",",
            "  \"provisioningState\": \"Succeeded\",",
            "  \"resourceGroup\": \"rg-name\",",
            "  \"tags\": null,",
            "  \"type\": \"Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts\"",
            "}"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: `(bastionhost.stdout | from_json).dnsName` right?

Comment: And then just don't put `"` around `{{ bh }}` if you don't want them in the final output.

Comment: @mdaniel, thank you for the info. I updated the set_fact to `bh: "{{ (bastionhost.stdout | from_json).dnsName }}"` and got this message at the end: `"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'dnsName'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user/getbastion.yml': line 61, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    register: bastionhost\n  - set_fact:\n    ^ here\n"`

Comment: Weird, from the output you gave in your question, `bastion.stdout` is a json object, not a list like the error is suggesting. Can you debug `msg={{ bastion.stdout | from_json }}`? (Edit your question to add this output)

Comment: @zigarn updated the question with the result. thank you for your help

Comment: Oh! Wait! Why are you reading the value from an intermediary file? The `stdout` of the `cat` is the bastion task results, not it's `stdout`. For it to work with this complicated behavior is to do `{{ ((bastionhost.stdout | from_json).stdout | from_json).dnsName }}`. The solution of mdaniel works if you just use it in place of the `regex_search` of the play you show at the beginning.

Comment: @zigarn thank you for the good info. Unfortunately, using `{{ ((bastionhost.stdout | from_json).stdout | from_json).dnsName }}` gave undefined value error: `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ ((bastionhost.stdout | from_json).stdout | from_json).dnsName }})` which i experimented on to come up with set_fact of `bh: "{{ (bastionhost.stdout | from_json).dnsName }}"` and it worked. Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mdaniel's:

```
  - set_fact:
      bh: "{{ (bastionhost.stdout | from_json).dnsName }}"
```